# Nativescript documentation for NS Core with Typescript

Tags: nativescript

When building a NS application I usually use Nativescript Core + Typescript.  In the latest version of the documentation, I noticed that this combination does not exist anymore.

I am not sure if this is related, but I also noticed that when I call **tns run android/ios** the Typescript files do not get transpiled automatically anymore when changes are made to the source code.  I have to call **tsc** manually to generate the corresponding javascript files.  This started happening after I upgraded to version 4.1+

Has Telerik switch direction and not encouraging NS Core + Typescript anymore?  Do I have to choose between Angular + Typescript and Core + Javascript now?

Just curious in the direction we are heading.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure about the documentation and the direction the NS is taking regarding the NS Core + Typescript combo, but with the help of tsonevn from the Telerik team I was able to get the automatic generation of JS files fixed.

It turns out that this was caused by the fact that the hooks folder was missing. Once I removed the node_modules and platform folders and ran **tns run android** everything started working again.

You can read more about it at: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5998